# finding FL and FH from continuous time signal

Tags: fourier-transform, bandpass

I have a continuous signal $x_{a}$ which is defined as $X_{a}(F)=0$ for $|F|>B$.
Now if I multiplied the continuous signal $x_{a}$ by $cos6\pi Bt$. Then the fourier transform of the signal can be defined as the following:

$$
Y(F)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{x_{a}(t)\ cos6\pi Bt\  e^{j2\pi Ft}}
$$
$$
\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \  =\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{x_{a}(t)\  e^{j2\pi(F + 3B)t}} + \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{x_{a}(t)\  e^{j2\pi(F - 3B)t}}
$$
$$
\qquad \qquad \qquad=\frac{1}{2}\ X_{a}(F+3B) + \frac{1}{2}\ X_{a}(F-3B)
$$

From that equation how do I find the $F_{H}$ and $F_{L}$ of my new continous time signal. This problem is taken from problems 6.1 in Digital Signal Processing 4th Edition by Proakis & Manolakis. Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: What are $F_H$ and $F_L$ ?

Comment: Hint: $X_a(\cdot)$ is a _function_ with the property that the function has value $0$ whenever the magnitude of its argument exceeds $B$. So, $X_a(F-3B)$ has value $0$ whenever $F-3B > B$ or $F-3B < -B$, that is, for $F>4B$ or $F < 2B$.

Comment: Thank you sir, now I got the idea, The key idea is this ilustration $F−3B>B$ and $F−3B<−B$